# How to run a bash script, but skip the last 2 lines?

Tags: bash

I can run a bash script with `./script_name.sh`. Is there a way to run a bash script, but telling it to not run the code last two lines of the file?

Comment: This would be ugly and fragile. Have you considered adding an option to `./script_name.sh` so that you can run e.g. `./script_name.sh -n` to skip that particular part of it?

Comment: If this is a one-off change, just comment the last two lines out and run the script normally. If this is something that you'll do frequently, modify the code to add an option to disable the *behavior* you want to suppress (whether that be 2 lines or 200 lines).

Comment: please do what the commenters suggested, especially if you're going to put this in some sort of automated pipeline

Answer (score 4):

With head from GNU coreutils:

```
head -n -2 ./script_name.sh | bash
```

Answer (score 3):

If your `head` command supports negative (EOF-relative) line numbers, you can use this:

```
bash <(head -n -2 script_name.sh)
```

Warning: I don't even want to think about the number of ways this could go badly.

Answer (score 2):

You can make a script that will read all but the last two lines of a file into another file, and then run that as a script.